# What's the minimum value of the following function?

Tags: functions

So, I need to figure out the minimum value of this function:

\begin{equation*}
y=x^2-2(m+1)x+2m(m+2).
\end{equation*}

I tried with the y-coordinate of the parabola's tip, but all I get is the following:

\begin{equation*}
\frac{(4m^2-4m+14)}{4}
\end{equation*}

which makes no sense. How do I determine it? It must be easy...

Comment: what is $m$ here?

Comment: What do you mean by "it must be easy..." and what is m? Can you use calculus?

Comment: m is a parameter (real number). Thank you everyone for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

$$y'(x)=2x-2(m+1)=0$$ which gives $$x=m+1$$ plugging this in you equation we obtain
$$y(m+1)=(m+1)^2-2(m+1)^2+2m(m+2)=....$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
y&=x^2-2(m+1)x+2m(m+2)\\&=[x-(m+1)]^2-(m+1)^2+2m(m+2)\\&=[x-(m+1)]^2+(m^2+2m-1)\\&=[x-(m+1)]^2+(m+1)^2-2
\end{align}

So $\min{(y)}$ when $x=m+1$ and $\min{[(m+1)^2-2]}$

And $\min{[(m+1)^2-2]}$ when $m=-1$ have a value of $-2$

Therefore $\min{(y)}=-2$